# Let's get critical: Apr 2014 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Gardening & Landscaping Stack Exchange](http://gardening.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Final Results

- [What is this thorny leafless tree with lumpy yellow fruit?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/9050/what-is-this-thorny-leafless-tree-with-lumpy-yellow-fruit)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [What is this deciduous tree with sharp edged leaves and clusters of small flowers?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/9059/please-help-identify-weird-tree)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [What should I do to encourage my Hyacinth to flower again?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/9013/what-should-i-do-to-encourage-my-hyacinth-to-flower-again)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Why is triclopyr not available in California?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/8968/why-is-triclopyr-not-available-in-california)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [How soon can I start training or pruning a seedling?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/9018/how-soon-can-i-start-training-or-pruning-a-seedling)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [What is this 3 metre tall shrub whose bottom comes from lots of thick stems?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/9024/plant-identification-its-shrub-about-3-metres-high-at-the-bottom-comes-from)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Peas as green manure](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/9027/peas-as-green-manure)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [How deep are the roots of a Dwarf Southern Magnolia tree?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/9042/how-deep-are-the-roots-of-a-dwarf-southern-magnolia-tree)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Can woodpeckers damage a pecan tree enough that it won't produce?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/9005/can-woodpeckers-damage-a-pecan-tree-enough-that-it-wont-produce)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [How to keep my roses fresh?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/9092/how-to-keep-my-roses-fresh)

**Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 3)

---